# One Xib file for 2 states: showing & editing a object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xib

The contacts application of the iPhone is a good illustration of my problem. Apple uses one view to show and edit contacts at the same time. When a user wants to edit a contact he simply presses the edit button on the right side of the navcontroller. The 'show contact' interface changes to the 'edit contact' interface and the user is able to edit the contact. When the user is finished editing he presses the 'done' button.

My question is, what is the easiest way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: I accepted Alen Moore's answer, it worked best for me to just show and hide controls that need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the iPhone CoreData Recipes sample code has everything you need, they have a page that is exactly as you describe:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

The short answer is that you can achieve this by using to separate view xibs which you can swap in and out.  Personally I prefer to simply use code to hide and show the controls that need to change between the two views.

Comment: Let's check it out! If you should use your own way by simple using code to hide and show the controls that need to change, how would you implement that? Could you maybe add it to your answer?

Comment: Yeah, well the sample code kind of does the same but it uses a tableview for the editing.. maybe thats just the way, since the contacts app is using that too but this sample code project is so complicated! Maybe the 'change it with code' is a better idea.

Comment: I think it really depends on how complex your views are.  You can just add all of the controls for both modes, create IBOutlets and IBActions as needed, then set the .hidden to YES or NO when you want to show or hide a given control

Comment: I think that's a better solution, i'll try it tomorrow!